# Finger print scanner using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, adafruit

[image]Any help is greatly appreciated! Trying to build a small door lock that is controlled by a finger print sensor, (I know it will not be very practical). My issue is with putting the hardware together, I have the sensor connected to the Arduno uno with the green and yellow to pins 2 and 3 respectively, then the red and black to the ground and 5V rail. My issue is not knowing how to go about connecting the adafruit chip to the breadboard as I am going to try to use wifi for this project. Secondly I noticed most people use the adafruit Fingerprint sensor which has the module and mine is just a cheap sensor from amazon and was wondering if it will still be able to work the same? Sorry for all the questions I am very new to this and I apologize for sounding so lost haha, anything helps. 
[image]

Comment: you have not told us what device you actually have ... saying that you connected yellow and green wires does not mean anything specific

Comment: You should give us a link to that fingerprint sensor. Or even better: to it's datasheet

Comment: sorry my bad, here is the link: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07TZQ6YTH/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any information on the internet on how to use this device.   Did it come with any manual or documentation ?

Comment: No that is my issue,I am kind of lost now, was hoping I wouldn't have to buy a whole new sensor

Comment: please post a clear picture of the backside of the sensor .... make sure that it fills most of the frame

Comment: Just uploaded the backside of the sensor, hope the quality is good enough!